# *13 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi

I am configuring for 1st time and getting this error.
Nginx site-enabled config is as follows:

```
#tream component nginx needs to connect to
 upstream django1 {
#server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
server unix:///run/uwsgi/app/apps/sokcet.B;
 }

# configuration of the server
server {

# the port your site will be served on
listen 9000;

# the domain name it will serve for
server_name xxx.xxx.xx.xxx; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
charset     utf-8;

# max upload size
client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

# Django media
#location /media  {
#    alias /path/to/your/mysite/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
#}

#location /static {
#    alias /path/to/your/mysite/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
#}

# Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django1;
    include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    uwsgi_read_timeout 1800;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
}
}
```

Uwsgi is running but nginx is giving this error.
So kindly tell me what is the issue in my configuration.

Comment: `nginx` is telling you that `django1` closed the connection. You need to be looking at your application for the cause.

Comment: I am ruuning ngnix and uwsgi and uwsgi is running

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream